# Do the idempotents in an inverse semigroup commute?

Tags: semigroups, inverse-semigroups

I have been looking at this for hours now. Why is it true that idempotents of an inverse semigroup commute? It seems like this should be straightforward but I just can't get it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In future please specify which definitions you're using, since, for instance, some authors define an inverse semigroup as a regular semgroup whose idempotents commute.

Comment: you could just give the OP the benefit of the doubt that s/he is not aware of this fact, assume s/he thinks that the definitions are universal (as most definitions are or almost are), and that this was not a lazy act on part of the person asking the question.  You could have just as easily asked for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that $S$ is an inverse semigroup, and let $e, f\in S$ be arbitrary two idempotents.
Then
$$(ef)(f(ef)^{-1}e)(ef)=ef^2(ef)^{-1}e^2f=ef(ef)^{-1}ef=ef$$
$$(f(ef)^{-1}e)(ef)(f(ef)^{-1}e)=f(ef)^{-1}e^2f^2(ef)^{-1}e=f((ef)^{-1}ef(ef)^{-1})e=f(ef)^{-1}e.$$
Therefore, by the uniqueness of inverses, $f(ef)^{-1}e=(ef)^{-1}$.
It follows that
$$
(ef)^{-2}=(f(ef)^{-1}e)^2=f((ef)^{-1}ef(ef)^{-1})e=f(ef)^{-1}e=(ef)^{-1},
$$
i.e. $(ef)^{-1}$ is an idempotent and so $(ef)^{-1}=ef$. 
By symmetry, $fe$ is also an idempotent.

So,
$$
(ef)(fe)(ef)=efef=ef,\ (fe)(ef)(fe)=fefe=fe,
$$
and so $fe=(ef)^{-1}=ef$, as required.

Comment: Nice, can you recommend a text on semi-groups that contains this stuff?

Comment: I'd recommend John Howie's book called "Fundamentals of semigroup theory" from 1995.

Comment: That book looks nice, could you recommend another one plase? One on the cheaper side of things?

Comment: Lawson's [*Inverse Semigroups: The Theory of Partial Symmetries*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Inverse-Semigroups-Theory-Partial-Symmetries/dp/9810233167) fits the bill, @JorgeFernández, but beware: Lawson's use of $\mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ was switched - I think to ease notation at the time.