# Prove that a semigroup with operation * is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(S,*)$ be a semigroup such that for every $a \in S$ there exists $b \in S$ such that $a*b*a=a$. Prove that $S$ is a group.
I tried first to prove that $1$ exists but I can't get my head around it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Such a semigroup is called [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_semigroup), and need not be a group in general. For a counterexample see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=zDJjuFggG4gC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=a+regular+semigroup+which+is+not+a+group&source=bl&ots=DUZYn0DAjz&sig=nqhAT4rwn7iUwawjTsLwBVo0rbU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBWoVChMIwcW5kbeYyQIVijsUCh2__ATh#v=onepage&q=a%20regular%20semigroup%20which%20is%20not%20a%20group&f=false).
However, if we require that for each $a\in S$ there is a *unique* $b\in S$ with $aba=a$, then $S$ is a group - this is a duplicate, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420461/help-me-prove-equivalently-of-regular-semigroup-and-group).